# How to randomize curved lines in Sketch to create a pattern?

Tags: vector, sketch-app, patterns

I'm looking to figure out a method to automate randomized curved lines to achieve an effect similar to the image below

[image: lined pattern]

Answer (score 1):

You can automate randomized rotation in sketch-app using [Looper plugin](http://sureskumar.com/looper/).

Example:

[image]